# Can I define a config xml file in Icenium?

Tags: config, telerik-appbuilder

Does anyone know if I can use a different config.xml with Icenium?

I know that with phonegap I can define a config.xml under **www** folder.

Can I do the same with Icenium? If yes, where should I put my config.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definitely. See [this documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/configuring-your-project/edit-configuration) for more information on how to do this.